# Page redirect is being ignored in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, routes

folders are set up like this

-public

```
 -landing
      -landing.html
 -Login
      -login.html
 -register
       -register.html
```

-routes

```
 -HTMLroutes
 -APIroutes
```

- server.js

everything that is commented out are things ive tried with no success

if (bcrypt.compare(req.body.user.password, user.Password)){

```
            console.log("successful login")
            // res.send({redirect: '/app'}) 
            // res.redirect("app")
            // return res.redirect("/app")
            // res.sendFile(path.join("./public/landing/landing.html"))
            // res.sendFile('./landing/landing.html', { root: "public" })
```

}

landing.html is the page i want the user to see. whether i load it by redirecting the route to something like "/app" or by loading the page.

"res.sendFile(path.join...)" is what i got furthest with but my error says the file path is not "Absolute"

in my server.js i use express.static("public"), i know that plays a role somehow

however every time i test this, i get console.log("successful login") working but nothing else. Like it just ignores any type of redirect command i give it.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `res.sendFile` needs a absolute path. You can use `path.resolve` to get a absolute path, `path.join` will just "join" or put the paths together and the path will "relative"

Comment: Thanks for the input, i tried that but it ignored it just giving me the "successful login" output